# How to do a refund in Stripe?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, stripe-payments

I am trying to make a refund in Stripe

```
require "stripe"

Stripe.api_key = "sk_test_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
refund = Stripe::Refund.create(
  :charge => "ch_16fdjakjlfcCAuPNIGx6R4o"
)
  end
```

But I'm getting this error

> undefined method `create' for Stripe::Refund:Class

I do have `gem 'stripe'` in my gemfile

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's worth checking the version of the stripe gem you are using. Earlier versions refunded a charge directly from the charge object rather than creating an explicit refund. E.g.

```
charge = Stripe::Charge.retrieve("ch_123")
charge.refund
```

It looks like this approach will still work with the latest stripe gem too although the documentation does point at the `Stripe::Refund` approach that you've tried so I assume that that is the preferred way with the latest gem.